# Python Math significance level

Tags: python, math, significant-digits

I have from a dataset I load in 2 values.

```
x1=5.904e-16
```

and

```
x1=1.048576e-14
```

granted these are tiny numbers, but all I want to do is average them.

```
avg = 1/2*(x1+x2)
```

but this gives avg = 0

Arr!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using Python 2.

When both arguments are integers, Python 2 uses **integer division**, which means that the result will also be an integer. For example:

```
print 1/2
# 0
print 5/2
# 2
```

To overcome this, either use the float equivalent (`0.5`), or change one of the arguments to the division (either `1` or `2`, doesn't matter) to a float, so that it will return a float as well.

```
print 1.0/2
# 0.5
print 1/2.0
# 0.5
print 1.0/2.0
# 0.5
```

You could also, as [nneonneo mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545354/python-math-significance-level/14545368#comment20288884_14545368), put the sum straight into the division, like so:

```
(x1+x2)/2.0
```

This will also give the desired result.

Comment: Or, simpler, `(x1+x2)/2.0`.

Answer (score -2):

```
avg = 0.5*(x1+x2)
```

worked because 1/2 apparently in python is not equal to 0.5 but no it sees 1/2 as one over two and no values past a decimal on either so it assumes you do not care about wanting that.

Comment: `1/2` evaluates to `0` in Python *2.x* (and C and many other similar languages); *why*? There is no point trying to explain it further.